# How to Update Array Index After Drag and Drop is Called in UserDefaults in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, nsuserdefaults

I'm Creating an demo, In this I have Drag and Drop Functionality , Drag and Drop function is working Perfectly Fine, My Concern is , when I close the app and came back to the View again, the same is Index is showing in the array, I want to Get the array as I do Drag and Drop at a index.

**Here's My Code**

**CollectionView Methods**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.lbl.text = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.img.layer.cornerRadius = cell.img.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.lbl.layer.cornerRadius = cell.lbl.frame.size.width / 2
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width / 2) - 20, height: 200)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let item = array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "data")
    array.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
    defaults.set(item, forKey: "data")
    defaults.synchronize()
    
    print(item )
}
```

**View Did Load and LongPressGesture Methods**

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var array = ["Fateh", "Parul", "Jitendra", "Javed", "Brijesh","Pandey Ji"]
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var longPress : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "data") == nil {
         // userDefault has a value
   
        defaults.set(array, forKey: "data")
        
    } else  {
        let newData = defaults.object(forKey: "data")
        array = newData as! [String]
    }
    
    
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndex = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndex)
    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view))
        
    case .ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        defaults.synchronize()
    @unknown default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, if there is no data already saved in UserDefaults, you are doing this:

```
defaults.set(array, forKey: "data")
```

You're setting the **array** as the data.

In `moveItemAt`, you're doing this:

```
defaults.set(item, forKey: "data")
```

You're setting only an individual **item** as the data, when you should be setting the updated **array** as the data.

As a side note, there is no need for `defaults.synchronize()` ... from Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize):

> **synchronize()**
>
> Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.